# HTTP POST turns into OPTIONS AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, http-post, angularjs-http

I'm trying to submit a login form to a rest Api, translating my Jquery/Javascript code into AngularJS. I try to use `$http` service for send the request, but when I submit the form, the POST request turns into OPTIONS and no request params are passed to. This is my code:

```
controller.formData = {
    username :  $scope.formData.username,
    password :  $scope.formData.password,
};
$http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'http://localhost:8080/multe-web/signin',
      data    : controller.formData,  
      headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }  
     })
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
     });
```

This is a screenshoot of browser's console
[image: This is a screenshoot of browser's console]

Why no parameters are passed to the HTTP POST request?
[image: Why no parameters are passed to the HTTP POST request?]

Can someone help me?

Comment: I believe you are running into cors policy hickups. The browser will preflight your post with an options request.

Comment: I edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do a Cross Origin Request, this could be a **'[preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)'**:

See this post: [How to disable OPTIONS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/how-to-disable-options-request)

Comment: How should I change my source code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This request is called "preflight request". This appends when you try to access a resource that is from another domain. For more information you can search for Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS). During the preflight request, you should see headers starting with `Access-Control-Request-*` These request headers are asking the server for permissions to make the actual request. Your preflight response needs to acknowledge these headers in order for the actual request to work.

Comment: How should I change my source code to accomplish this?

Comment: You can host your web page and your api on the same domain. Or you can handle the OPTIONS request on your web server to return the expected headers

Answer (score 0):

The `OPTIONS` that you see is a pre-flighted request that is initiated by the browser. This happens due to `CORS` that stands for "CROSS ORIGIN RESOURCE SHARING`.

[Pre-flighted requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Preflight_example)

In your case, your backend server needs to acknowledge the `OPTIONS` request and send a 200 back. Only then the browser fires the real `POST` request

Here are some links to get you started 
[Same Origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)
[AngularJS and CORS](https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/)
[Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365303/what-is-the-issue-cors-is-coming-to-solve)

Comment: How should I change my source code to accomplish this?

Comment: So, your backend needs to acknowledge the `OPTIONS` by a 200. What kind of server do you have in your backend? Java/NodeJs..etc?

Comment: My backend is a Java server.

Comment: Try [these](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=enable%20cors%20java) topics. The idea is to make your server send a 200 for the options. And apply security policies accordingly

Comment: In my backend CORS is enabled. The HTTP POST doesn't  have any request params, so I think this is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must define a CORS filter on your backend. 
I don't know which language you are using but an example in spring framework (java) would be the following.

```
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, cache-control, content-type, Origin, key");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Basically you are stating that `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` can come from any domain. ( in a production environment you would limit this offcourse to your known domains ).

When implementing this filter your options request will pass through without problems.

The options call is something the browser does automatically and you really don't want to disable this as some other answers are suggesting.

Kind regards

Comment: In my backend CORS is already enabled. The problem is that in the HTTP POST body no params are passed to (look at the second screenshoot in the question above). How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: show me your backend code where you define your rest endpoint please