# How to make HTTP Request work in Flutter web?

Tags: http, flutter, dart, httprequest, flutter-web

I am trying to fetch data from My site link: http://mrmatjar.com/kaka/dataaza.php

Here is my code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:mrmatjar_afflite/shopobj.dart';
class Operations{
 static Future<List<ShopObj>> loly() async{
    List<ShopObj> ak= new List<ShopObj>();
      var res = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull("https://mrmatjar.com/kaka/dataaza"),headers: {"Accept":"application/json"});

    print(res);
    var v = json.decode(x.body);
    for(var h in v){
        ak.add(new ShopObj(h['title'], h['cost'], h['earn'], h['image']));
    }
    return ak;
  }
}
```

But it is not working.
when I run it the Web app Breaks and when I use Break point it shows file call by 
blinding.dart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem. It has to do with CORS. 
I added this to my server of the backend

```
sudo a2enmod headers

sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/headers.conf
```

modify like this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

then restart apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: What if You do not have to privileges to make changes to the server?

Comment: @ASADHAMEED, I don't think there is an answer to this one. From what I understand about CORS, it's a security policy to ensure that no one can make a site that leeches off your server. So if the server doesn't allow you access, you can't get it. See the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365303/what-is-the-issue-cors-is-trying-to-solve

Comment: @LeviLesches I dug a little deeper into the issue and I found that it's an issue with the browser implementing "Same Origin Policy" and the server side has to use the following parameter `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to allow all domains to access the server content or restrict it to some domains(Adding domain names instead of *). In my case, the server-side did not have this parameter set.

Comment: Right, which you cannot solve if you don't have control over the server.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to stack overflow :).

**First:**

I see some typo error in your code.

`var v = json.decode(x.body);` should be

`var v = json.decode(res.body);`

**Second:**

Once you fix the above you might face **Cross Origin Request(CORS)** error which may be because you have not set this up in your server. Especially if your flutter web application is not running in the same domain as the server where you api is running. Even if its on the same machine, you will have to allow the request from certain domain and ports. If you are not aware of CORS you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

**Third:**

As I see you are processing the response without checking the statusCode of the response it would still lead to an error when you try to decode the response.

I have a simple running example here based on the [DOGs public api](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/documentation/random).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HttpRequestDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HttpRequestDemoState createState() => _HttpRequestDemoState();
}

class _HttpRequestDemoState extends State<HttpRequestDemo> {
  String imageUrl = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Image.network(
            imageUrl,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
          ),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.cloud_download),
          onPressed: () {
            fetchData();
          },
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  fetchData() async {
    final res = await http.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var v = json.decode(res.body);
      setState(() {
        imageUrl = v['message'];
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This app will show a new dog photo every time you press the floating action button as shown below which is based on the response from the api.

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for helping.
I added this 2 lines to server and its now working perfectly 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

Thanks again :3

Comment: adding these headers to the server also not working

Comment: Depending on the server you might need to add Allow-Methods as well including OPTIONS