# Flutter web - call http.get throws exception

Tags: exception, dart, http-get, flutter-web

That works fine on Android/Desktop:

```
Future<List<City>> fetchCities() async {


  final response =
  await http.get(globals.url + '/city',
      headers: {HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: globals.apiVersion});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
    return compute(parseCities, response.body);
  } else {
    // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
    print('Failed to load cities');
    throw TextException(Strings.msg_session_expired);
  }
}
```

But when launching as web application, I'm getting an exception:

```
errors.dart:145 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._version
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:194)
    at Function._version (io_patch.dart:284)
    at Function.get version [as version] (platform_impl.dart:121)
    at get _version (platform.dart:74)
    at Function.desc.get [as _version] (utils.dart:75)
    at Function.get version [as version] (platform.dart:231)
    at Object._getHttpVersion (http_impl.dart:3234)
    at new _http._HttpClient.new (http_impl.dart:2071)
    at Function.new (http.dart:1473)
    at new io_client.IOClient.new (io_client.dart:23)
    at Function.new (client.dart:30)
    at _withClient (http.dart:165)
    at _withClient.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123)
    at Object._withClient (http.dart:164)
    at Object.get (http.dart:47)
    at fetchCities (mcity.dart:113)
    at fetchCities.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123)
```

Is there any workarond to make http.get requests working on flutter_web?

Answer (score 2):

The usage of `HttpHeaders.acceptHeader` could be the issue. Its part of `dart:io` library, which is not enabled for flutter web. You should try instead to set the headers differently. For e.g. based on this constant value [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-io/HttpHeaders/acceptHeader-constant.html) something as follows should work.

```dart
final response =
  await http.get(globals.url + '/city',
      headers: {"accept": globals.apiVersion});
```

In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557173/how-to-make-http-request-work-in-flutter-web/58591067#58591067) I have used the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package which shows that this package can be used for flutter web.

Comment: That does not help. As I can see, http uses dart.io internally and it still throws an error. It seems, I cannot use any custom headers, otherwise it will throw error.

Comment: I removed any headers from my call and I'm still getting the same error. I don't understand how did you make it working.

Comment: Can you include your import statements. You are right `http` package uses `dart:io` but it does so by conditionally importing them. Meaning it will alternate between `dart:html` and dart:io` depending on the context it is running. In your exception snapshot I see `at new io_client.IOClient.new (io_client.dart:23)` which is from `http` package. It is somehow picking the `io_client` instead of `browser_client`. Could you simply write how you deploy your code or run it..

Comment: I even removed dart.io from imports. Still I'm getting error. Flutter version from master channel. Which version have you tested?

Comment: I suppose this is the latest because i just upgraded to day morning. :)


Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.12.3-pre.49, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1069], locale de-DE)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.40.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202569/discussion-between-abhilash-chandran-and-user1209216).