# Integrate Identity server 4 with frameworl api (katana)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, identityserver4

I have a legacy project ( Framework not core ) and want to authorize this API with identity server 4 I found this connect to connect with identity server 4 using katana
I have identity server 4 with an angular client - API resource (.net FrameWork not core )
the cors not work with UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication , if it is removed it work correctly
In Identity serve I defined the client as

```
     new Client
                {
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    ClientId = "insig_spa",
                    ClientName = "Insig SPA",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        Scopes.InsigApi
                    },
                    RedirectUris =
                    {
                        clientUrl + "/auth-callback",
                        clientUrl + "/assets/silent-refresh.html"
                    },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { clientUrl + "/logout" },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = { clientUrl ,"https://localhost:44368" },
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 300,
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
                }
new ApiScope(Scopes.InsigApi, "Access API Backend")
 new ApiResource(Instances.InsigApi, "Resource Insig API")
                {
                    Scopes = new List<string>()
                    {
                        Scopes.InsigApi
                    }
                }
and in the webapi ( FrameWork not Core ) :

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "cookie"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "insig_spa",
                Authority = "https://localhost:5000",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5002/auth-callback",
                Scope = "openid profile email insigapi.read",

                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "cookie",

                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                UseTokenLifetime = false,

                RedeemCode = true,
                SaveTokens = true,
                ClientSecret = "secret",

                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                ResponseMode = "query",

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                    {
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                        {
                            // set PKCE parameters
                            var codeVerifier = CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(32);

                            string codeChallenge;
                            using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
                            {
                                var challengeBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier));
                                codeChallenge = Base64Url.Encode(challengeBytes);
                            }

                            n.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("code_challenge", codeChallenge);
                            n.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("code_challenge_method", "S256");

                            // remember code_verifier (adapted from OWIN nonce cookie)
                            RememberCodeVerifier(n, codeVerifier);
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = n =>
                    {
                        // get code_verifier
                        var codeVerifier = RetrieveCodeVerifier(n);

                        // attach code_verifier
                        n.TokenEndpointRequest.SetParameter("code_verifier", codeVerifier);

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                }
            });
```

in console i found :  https://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?client_id=insig_spa&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5002%2Fauth-callback&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20insigapi.read&code_challenge=A6ToJOXINiypamObt21YJan7e1TYuwxQa-_drBSgEaw&code_challenge_method=S256&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DPg1Xgh0YlELfO3mDIa1xWw4yAVjwAnA_O8qb83daZyzMNJsv7ZFxdFIbht7hDo4vQb-q5JdrozvYCTpIC2HVTnx1DQ8Wz9s1d06YoL8hdwUGF-yisgodvAg0sphJ1Qk_F1NXs5r5XlzA_HFb1PYgDnn6aAbcYi5wCtoIAVUiDOd2kjIJ_hXh7ez9fk6pdmnvbyXnDtp9q-cAPcwjr8bj8fOApBzRplJYBFGHj6VGYVoFdUb20-5yonekbW6Ppkv2Y7nkk3a06P1nYYB4Xow-DElLZt-qWKovKd0fU5Xdntc&nonce=637867398003742436.YWIyNDEwYWItMjc1OC00NjY3LThmZWMtYjAxYjc2MjE1MTYxMThjNDJlOGQtZWVhYi00ZTk4LWIzY2EtZTgyZDQ2ZDAzN2Vm&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0' (redirected from 'https://localhost:44368/values') from origin 'https://localhost:5002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Why this error and how can i fix it

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365303/what-is-the-issue-cors-is-trying-to-solve) can help you?

Comment: Hello, welcome. Maybe this can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Good luck.