# Auto press the Next button of a widget after 5 secs

Tags: javascript, widget, getelementsbyname

I have the following widget on my website which loads a booking system.
Is there a way to press the Next button after 5 seconds of loading?

```
<!-- Practice Better Booking Widget: start -->
<style>.better-inline-booking-widget{position:relative;overflow:hidden}.better-inline-booking-widget iframe{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%}</style>

<div class="better-inline-booking-widget" data-url="https://my.practicebetter.io" data-course="63bdc7debc7ce781dd1860e0" data-hash="600ad6742a9c2416e0768660" data-theme="54a288" data-theme-accent="d74b33" style="width:100%;max-width:550px;height:800px;" data-scrollbar-visible="false"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.practicebetter.io/assets/js/booking.widget.js"></script>
<!-- Practice Better Booking Widget: end -->
```

I tried to add `setTimeout(document.getElementsByName("Next").click(),5000);` with no success

Comment: There is no next button in the provided HTML.

Comment: I guess it loads it from the main platform...

Answer (score 0):

The button that's being rendered by your JavaScript is actually contained in an [i-frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). i-frames follow the [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) policy. This means that if you want to [interact with the contents of the i-frame](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication#:%7E:text=The%20%E2%80%9CSame%20Origin%E2%80%9D%20policy%20states,full%20access%20to%20that%20window.) (including the button) via JavaScript in the page hosting the i-frame they both need to be on the same domain. If they are in the same domain then this is how you would click the button with JavaScript.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    let button = document.querySelector('.better-inline-booking-widget iframe').contentWindow.document.querySelector('button');
    button.click();  // This will throw an error unless the site is the same domain as the iframe
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
Unfortunately they are not on the same domain.
Are there any other ways to go around this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only other way around this is getting the server of the i-frame to enable cross-origin resource sharing by adding your domain to their list or if you own both domains you can use this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame). Check out this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365303/what-is-the-issue-cors-is-trying-to-solve) of why this security feature was designed as it is.